# Is there a way to get more than 5 digits of precision when using a double in a QGIS memory layer?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, precision

```
addressLayer = QgsVectorLayer("Point?crs=epsg:4326&field=address:string(50)&field=city:string(50)&field=state:string(50)&field=zipcode:string(50)&field=elevation:double(20,8)&field=latitude:double(20,8)&field=longitude:double(20,8)&index=yes", "Search Results", "memory")
```

This is the line I used to make the layer. I have tried other combinations such as double(15, 8) etc. but the layer still defaults to length of 20 and precision of 5 for the double data type. I can't seem to find any documentation on this behavior.

Any ideas?

Comment: I didn't observe this behavior in code of my answer. Which version of QGIS and operative system type do you have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried out your line in my next short code, with fictional data, and it works perfectly.

```
uri = "Point?crs=epsg:4326&field=address:string(50)&field=city:string(50)&field=state:string(50)&field=zipcode:string(50)&field=elevation:double(20,8)&field=latitude:double(20,8)&field=longitude:double(20,8)&index=yes"

addressLayer = QgsVectorLayer(uri, 
                              "Search Results", 
                              "memory")

prov = addressLayer.dataProvider()

feat = QgsFeature()

feat.setAttributes(["", "", "", "", 1, 1, 1])

prov.addFeatures([feat])

QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(addressLayer)
```

After running the code at the Python Console of QGIS I got:

[image]

You can see that all double fields have 8 digits for their precision.

When I force the situation to have elevation field with 20 digits:

```
.
.
.
feat.setAttributes(["", "", "", "", 10000000000000000000, 1, 1])
.
.
.
```

result is similar: 8 digits precision; as it can be watched at next image.

[image]

Comment: yeah, it started working for me yesterday after i switched to a different project. no idea why but i am not having any issues with it now. thank you though for your help.